# Query Optimization related to View and BLOB column

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g, query-optimization

Suppose I'm using Oracle 11g, and have:

```
create table t1(
n1 number,
n2 blob);

create view v1 as
select n1, n2 from t1;
```

In this case, if I ran:

```
select n1 from v1;
```

Will n2 be fetched from database? How can I confirm it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the explain plan saying?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oracle fetch only listed columns.

You can do this experiment.

set serveroutput on

```
create or replace function blabla return varchar2
is 
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Hello World');
return 'blabla function';
end;


create view  test_fetch as select 'abc' col1, blabla col2 from dual;

select col1,col2 from test_fetch;

select col1 from test_fetch;
```

After these queries in output you will see only one line.

Comment: The question is about performance. I don't think your answer touches that point.

Comment: @Nitish Question is about "if n2 column will be fetched from database". And answer is not. If column is not listed in select it will not be fetched. My example is only proof. Not executing function or fetching blob have big impact on performance.

Comment: @Nitish I'm sorry but i don't understand your doubts about my answer

Comment: Tags in the question contain `performance` and `query-optimization`. IMHO, the answer should address this.

Comment: IMHO I should to answer the question or give tips how to resolve problem. Or we have different imagination how does stackoverflow work.

Comment: I don't imagine how things work. I read. You might want to read the Help section and Tour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138526/discussion-between-nitish-and-arkadiusz-lukasiewicz).